# Insert data into 2d array from file via split?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, 2d

How could one populate a 2d array from a text file using split?

`String proxies[][] = {{"127.0.0.1","80"}, {"127.0.0.1","443"}, {"127.0.0.1","3306"}};`

In my text file I have data with a ip:port on each line:

```
127.0.0.1:80
127.0.0.1.443
127.0.0.1.3306
```

I could populate a 1d array using split like this:

```
proxies = everyLine.split("\\n");
```

How would I insert the ip:port data into a 2d array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String[] lines = everyLine.split("\\n");
    String[][] proxies = new String[lines.length][];
    int i=0;
    for ( String line : lines )
    {
        proxies[i++] = line.split(":");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java constructs it's not possible. You can use Apache Commons method [`FileUtils#lineIterator(File, String)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#lineIterator%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) to iterate over lines and apply `String.split(String)` on each

Answer (score 0):

you could split on the `:` operator.

```
String []proxies = everyLine.split("\\n");
for(int i=0;i<proxies.length;i++){
 String[] anotherDimention= proxies[i].split(":");
// do something useful with it
}
```